# How to fitting AGGD(Asymmetric generalized normal distribution) in R?

Tags: r, function, package, fitdistrplus

I want to fitting about asymmetric generalized normal distribution. What is the package and function to implement it in R? It's not easy to find them.

I tried to find R-package and function about it. I want AGGD fitting model to fit for asymmetric distribution data.

Comment: `library(gnorm)` implements symmetric generalized normal distributions ,and there is `mggd`for multivarante gaussian distributions. For the assymetric I could not find anything. Possible that there is nothing public . If you are looking for assymetric shaped distribution in general, maybe the beta distribution family could also work for you.